# Condition for several columns

Tags: pandas

How to do in pandas something like this:

```
if df["Segment"].isin([1]):
    df["col1"] = 1
    df["col2"] = 2
    df["col3"] = 3
elif df["Segment"].isin([2]):
    df["col1"] = 11
    df["col2"] = 21
    df["col3"] = 31
```

There is an `ValueError: The truth of a Series is ambiguous`. There a lot of code under each `elif`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with mask, columns in list and list of values (same like length of columns list):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'Segment':[4,1,4,2,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})


df.loc[df["Segment"].isin([1,2]), ['C','D','E']] = [10,20,30]
df.loc[df["Segment"].isin([4]), ['C','D','E']] = [100,200,300]
print (df)
   A  Segment    C    D    E  F
0  a        4  100  200  300  a
1  b        1   10   20   30  a
2  c        4  100  200  300  a
3  d        2   10   20   30  b
4  e        5    2    1    2  b
5  f        4  100  200  300  b
```